# Windows IFS: own filesystem VS notepad.exe

Tags: windows, filesystems, wdk

Windows 10 x64 - implemented own filesystem, the usual directory traversal, copying, reading, deleting files work in DOS, git bash, and explorer.

But can not read files in notepad.exe!

I have a "hello world" text file named "a.file.txt" on my filesystem drive E:, and if I try to read it in notepad, using "notepad.exe E:\a.file.txt" I get the error:
"%1 is not a valid Win32 application".
However, a "copy E:\a.file.txt C:\a.file.txt ; notepad.exe C:\a.file.txt" works just fine. wordpad.exe also works fine.

Since I print *all* IRPs coming my way, there isn't much scope for what could be wrong (I hope). In particular, running notepad.exe it only goes through a handful of queries. I have skipped `CLEANUP` and `CLOSE`, as all I do is return `STATUS_SUCCESS` and `Information=0`.

```
IRP_MJ_CREATE: FileObject FFFFC686327AAB20 name '\' flags 0x0
dispatcher: exit: 0x0 OK Information 0x1
query_directory_FileFullDirectoryInformation: starting Search pattern 'a.file.txt' type 3 Index 0, Restart 0, Single 1
comparing names 'a.file.txt' == 'a.file.txt'
dispatcher: exit: 0x0 OK Information 0x78
IRP_MJ_CREATE: FileObject FFFFC68632887080 name '\a.file.txt' flags 0x0
dispatcher: exit: 0x0 OK Information 0x1
fsDispatcher: enter: major 10: minor 0: IRP_MJ_QUERY_VOLUME_INFORMATION
query_volume_information: FileFsVolumeInformation
dispatcher: exit: 0x80000005 Overflow Information 0x18
fsDispatcher: enter: major 5: minor 0: IRP_MJ_QUERY_INFORMATION
query_information: FileAllInformation
   file_basic_information
   file_standard_information
   file_position_information
   * query_information: FileNameInformation
   file_name_information: remaining space 8 str.len 20 struct size 8
* file_name_information: partial name of "a"
dispatcher: exit: 0x80000005 Overflow Information 0x68
IRP_MJ_CREATE: FileObject FFFFC68631BD6BB0 name '\a.file.txt' flags 0x0
dispatcher: exit: 0x0 OK Information 0x1
fsDispatcher: enter: major 5: minor 0: IRP_MJ_QUERY_INFORMATION
* query_information: FileNetworkOpenInformation
dispatcher: exit: 0x0 OK Information 0x38
fsDispatcher: enter: major 18: minor 0: IRP_MJ_CLEANUP
dispatcher: exit: 0x0 OK Information 0x0
fsDispatcher: enter: major 2: minor 0: IRP_MJ_CLOSE
dispatcher: exit: 0x0 OK Information 0x0
IRP_MJ_CREATE: FileObject FFFFC68631AD39D0 name '\' flags 0x0
dispatcher: exit: 0x0 OK Information 0x1
fsDispatcher: enter: major 5: minor 0: IRP_MJ_QUERY_INFORMATION
query_information: FileNameInformation
* file_name_information: name of \
dispatcher: exit: 0x0 OK Information 0xa
fsDispatcher: enter: major 10: minor 0: IRP_MJ_QUERY_VOLUME_INFORMATION
* query_volume_information: FileFsVolumeInformation
dispatcher: exit: 0x0 OK Information 0x20
fsDispatcher: enter: major 10: minor 0: IRP_MJ_QUERY_VOLUME_INFORMATION
query_volume_information: FileFsAttributeInformation
dispatcher: exit: 0x0 OK Information 0x18
fsDispatcher: enter: major 5: minor 0: IRP_MJ_QUERY_INFORMATION fsDeviceObject
query_information: FileBasicInformation
dispatcher: exit: 0x0 OK Information 0x28
```

Now, I believe I am correct in returning `OVERFLOW` in `FileFsVolumeInformation` and `FileAllInformation`, but I still fill in all the information, just truncating the VolumeName and Filename respectively.

As for what I return, I set `Attributes` to either `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY` or `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL` - nothing else. In FileBasic/FileAll and DirectoryListing. When this was wrong, bash would show everything as character device, so I know it is now set, as they are regular files or directories.

Possibly related is that if I copy notepad.exe to E: I can not run it "This app can't run on this PC" or in bash "Exec format error". So it is as if I was returning the wrong filetype. But it is only 3 functions it calls, and only FileAttributes is related (and FileStandard's Directory boolean).

I have re-written the `OVERFLOW` logic a few times now, but I believe it is correct to set the `fileNameLength` to the total length needed to fit the name even if it didn't all fit, but Information field is the total size returned (never larger than input size) ?

What sort of sacrifice does notepad.exe need to work!?

Comment: I suggest trying to troubleshoot this from a different angle: using Sysinternals Process Monitor, compare the behaviour of notepad when opening a file on the C drive to the behaviour of notepad when opening a file on your volume.  Hopefully you'll be able to identify a specific operation that is behaving differently, that should give you a clue as to what the problem might be and allow you to reproduce it from your own code.

Comment: Yeah definitely need a different angle, or different set of eyes. I don't suppose there is a util where you can click on a file, then select the IRP_MAJOR function want to call, and it displays the results back, for easy compare between ntfs and own filesystem? That would be quite useful.

Comment: There seems to be http://www.zezula.net/en/fstools/filetest.html which is close to what I want. Notepad.exe differences seems to be either of fastio (supposed to be optional, but maybe it isn't) or paging IO (which should just call IRP_MJ_READ but maybe it isn't).

Comment: Using FileTest and FileSpy; one difference is FASTIO which I have not done yet. Compiled fastfat.sys without FASTIO and confirmed it still works, so I could rule that out. However, FileTest shows it fails to memory-map on my filesystem, and Notepad appears to use mmap extensively. This is most likely the issue, I need to work out why I fail mmap next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, notepad.exe is noteworthy in that it uses memory mapped files to read  files, and mmap files were not working in my filesystem. I used TestFile from zezula.net to notice that it was not working. To enable mmap to work, I had to assign `FileObject->SectionObjectPointer = &vp->SectionObjectPointers` in `IRP_MJ_CREATE`. Most cases this is stored in your `Fcb` (as in `FileObject->fscontext`) and is just defined as `SECTION_OBJECT_POINTERS SectionObjectPointers;`.

Some care is also needed to flush the mmap pages in `IRP_MJ_CLEANUP` as per `fastfat` sample sources.

Also related is the setup call `FsRtlRegisterFileSystemFilterCallbacks()` where you want to define at least `PreAcquireForSectionSynchronization` callback to handle locks for sections. Also in `fastfat` sources.